# Intuition behind the loss function in Deep Q learning?

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, loss-function, q-learning

I'm currently following a tutorial but I got stuck at the deep Q learning model. According to my understanding of neural networks they predict an approximate function for the inputs given with the help of the loss value, but in the deep Q case, the author of the tutorial said the loss is calculated as Q_target - Q. He told the Q_target is the Q value from the previous iteration. My doubt is if we're using Q value from old iteration to calc lot loss how is the network converging to predict a bellman like equation. Upon asking this doubt he changed his stand, he told that they use the target networks. Each different tutorial I'm trying to refer has a different notion for the Q_target and the loss function. That's why I'm confused. If we're using the "previous iteration's Q value - current Q value" as loss won't our network try to predict the model that predicts values that are closer to the previous iteration's Q values? And moreover for each and every epoch while training for the same state the Q_target will vary each time, so will the network predict a stable model? Can anyone help me by telling me the actual loss function?

[image: The replies the general Q/A got]

[image]

Comment: Hi Anjani, and welcome to Data Science stack exchange. These are very basic questions in reinforcement learning. Could you explain what you already have studied about reinforcement learning, so answerers know what level to pitch the answers at. For instance, have you read any of *Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction*? Or are you reading a tutorial or some code? It may help to say which and link it if so.

Comment: Hi, I'm currently following a tutorial but I got stuck at the deep Q learning model. According to my understanding of neural networks they predict an approximate function for the inputs given with the help of the loss value, but in the deep Q case, the author of the tutorial said the loss is calculated as Q_target - Q. He told the Q_target is the Q value from the previous iteration. My doubt is if we're using Q value from old iteration to calc lot loss how is the network converging to predict a bellman like equation. Upon asking this doubt he changed his stand, he told that they'll use...

Comment: He said they'll use the target networks. Each different tutorial I'm trying to refer has a different notion for the Q_target and the loss function. That's why I'm confused. If we're using the "previous iteration's Q value - current Q value" as loss won't our network try to predict the model that predicts values that are closer to the previous iteration's Q values? And moreover for each and every epoch while training for the same state the Q_target will vary each time, so will the network predict a stable model?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. They show a different kind of question than your original text. Could you please [edit] in some of this information to the question? It will help, because your question currently seems to ask for a new tutorial, but what you really need is some explanation about why the other tutorials you have read seem to be inconsistent or miss an important detail for you.

Comment: I have edited the question, can you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm not sure the edit helped. Your comments helped - please put some of them in. For the added paragraph: "the Q_target was given as the Q value of the current state from the previous iteration" this is incorrect so either the tutorial is incorrect, or more likely you have misunderstood something. Could you link the specific part of the tutorial that says this?

Comment: Hi, it's the deep learning tutorial from udemy. It's a paid course I don't think I'm supposed to link it here. Of you feel that loss function is wrong can you please tell me what the actual loss function is? I'm pretty sure I didn't misunderstand, I can attach the Q/A section of the tutorial here.

Comment: The loss function looks incorrect, but what you have given would be the semi-gradient of an MSE loss, which is normal, so I suspect you have misunderstood which part is the loss function. Your statement "the Q_target was given as the Q value of the current state from the previous iteration" does not make sense, so it is likely that here your interpretation of what you read is also slightly wrong. But I cannot tell that without seeing what is actually taught